# Intellij Idea multi-project wicket app does not find webapp

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, wicket

i am using Idea 13.1 CE and trying to start multi module project, but i am getting this error 
`WARN  - WebInfConfiguration        - Web application not found src/main/webapp
WARN  - WebAppContext              - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},src/main/webapp`

In netbeans this project works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to "Run/Debug Configuration" and set "Working directory" to $MODULE_DIR$

Comment: Thanks for fast answering